# Python SymPy's plotting legend when using multiple ranges

Tags: python, plot, legend, sympy

I am using SymPy's plotting module, but legends stop working when I start having multiple lines with different ranges (to plot a function f(x) whose definition depend on x like in the following example).
I actually haven't seen any example of this anywhere :

```
from sympy import *
plt = plot((x**2,(x,-1,0)),(x**3,(x,0,1)),label='$f(x)$',show=False)
plt[0].legend = True
plt.show()
```

Here the legend is ignored. I also tried

```
plt.legend = True
```

instead of specifying plt[0] but Python says

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

My final goal would be something like
[a plot with lines of multiple colors, representing functions which have a different definition before and after a given value of x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izxLP.png)
and I append them together, say, if plt1 and plt2 have both 2 parts,

```
plt = plt1
plt.append(plt2[0])
plt.append(plt2[1])
```

Does anyone know how label and legend work in this context?
Thank you.

Comment: I didn't know how to show the legend, turn it on -- your `plt[0].legend = True` helped to find the solution. It worked with the line:`trigPlot.legend = True`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing is to use matplotlib directly. You can ask sympy for the list of points that it would plot and then use them with matplotlib yourself like this:

```
In [9]: import sympy                                                                                                                           

In [10]: line1, line2 = sympy.plot((x**2,(x,-1,0)),(x**3,(x,0,1)),label='$f(x)$',show=False)                                                   

In [11]: x1, y1 = line1.get_points()                                                                                                           

In [12]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                       

In [13]: plt.plot(x1, y1)                                                                                                                      
Out[13]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x120a9da90>]

In [14]: plt.show()
```

Then you can use matplotlib's legend function.

Comment: Thank you, indeed having some more freedom from matplotlib tools is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to transfer to matplotlib, you could use: p[0].label = 'sth'.
For example:

```
p1 = plot(ylist[0], (x, 0, 1), legend = True, show = False)
p1[0].label = 'function1'
p2 = plot(ya, (x,0,1), legend = True, show = False)
p2[0].label = 'function2'
p1.append(p2[0])
p1.show()
```