# get_points when singularity functions are used

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I want to plot multiple functions from `sympy` in one graph, but have the functionality of `matplotlib`. (So I can do legends, etc.) There is a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62674821/python-sympys-plotting-legend-when-using-multiple-ranges) that shows how to do this. My problem arises when a plot contains something like `Heaviside()`.

Here I am defining three different functions to plot:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')

a = x
b = x*(x-1/2)
c = x*Heaviside(x-1/2)
```

I can plot `a` and `b` with `matplotlib`  like this:

```
line1, line2 = plot((a,(x,0,1)), (b,(x,0,1)), show = False)
x1, y1 = line1.get_points()
x2, y2 = line2.get_points()
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
```

This shows both plots on one graph. But if I try to plot `a` and `c` instead, it doesn't work.

```
line3, line4 = plot((a,(x,0,)),(c,(x,0,)), show = False)
x4, y4 = line4.get_points()
```

This crashes with the error `AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_coefficient'`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sympy's `Lambdify()` to convert the sympy function to a numpy function. And then use matplotlib to do all the plotting.  `Lambdify()` doesn't seem to know about `Heaviside` (`Lambdify` is also used internally by sympy's plotting). Providing an explicit conversion rule works around the problem.

Note that `from sympy import *` can lead to confusing errors, especially when also numpy is involved, as many names coincide. It is usually better to only import the functions that are really used.

```py
from sympy import symbols, Heaviside, lambdify, latex

x = symbols('x')

a = x
b = x * (x - 1 / 2)
c = x * Heaviside(x - 1 / 2)

modules = [{'Heaviside': lambda x: np.heaviside(x, 1)}, 'numpy']
a_np = lambdify(x, a, modules=modules)
b_np = lambdify(x, b, modules=modules)
c_np = lambdify(x, c, modules=modules)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.linspace(-5, 5, 200)
plt.plot(xs, a_np(xs), label='$' + latex(a) + '$')
plt.plot(xs, b_np(xs), label='$' + latex(b) + '$')
plt.plot(xs, c_np(xs), label='$' + latex(c) + '$')
plt.legend()
```

[image: sympy with Heaviside and matplotlib plotting]